# Re Sparkline chart in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, charts, dataset, expression, sparklines

I have created a report using sparklines but getting this error

The Y expression for chart refers to field AtoC. Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope of if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope. Letters in the names of fields must use the correct case.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks
Aruna

Comment: Please add a couple screenshots of your report, showing the dataset, dataset fields, your sparkline and the Y axis expression for this expression.

Answer (score 0):

The dataset you are referring to in your sparkline does not contain a field called `AtoC`.  Be careful that your capitalisation is correct, as SSRS expressions are case sensitive.